# Counting the number of times the values are more than the mean for a specific column in Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find the number of times the value in a certain column (in this case under "AveragePrice") is more than its mean & median. I calculated the mean using the below:

```
mean_AveragePrice = avocadodf["AveragePrice"].mean(axis = 0)
median_AveragePrice = avocadodf["AveragePrice"].median(axis = 0)
```

how do I count the number of times the values were more than the mean?

Sample of the Dataframe:

```
Date    AveragePrice    Total Volume    PLU4046 PLU4225 PLU4770 Total Bags
0   27/12/2015  1.33    64236.62    1036.74 54454.85    48.16   8696.87
1   20/12/2015  1.35    54876.98    674.28  44638.81    58.33   9505.56
2   13/12/2015  0.93    118220.22   794.70  109149.67   130.50  8145.35
3   06/12/2015  1.08    78992.15    1132.00 71976.41    72.58   5811.16
4   29/11/2015  1.28    51039.60    941.48  43838.39    75.78   6183.95
5   22/11/2015  1.26    55979.78    1184.27 48067.99    43.61   6683.91
6   15/11/2015  0.99    83453.76    1368.92 73672.72    93.26   8318.86
7   08/11/2015  0.98    109428.33   703.75  101815.36   80.00   6829.22
8   01/11/2015  1.02    99811.42    1022.15 87315.57    85.34   11388.36
```

Comment: You can do the following: `(avocadodf['AveragePrice'] > mean_AveragePrice).sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

mean_AveragePrice = avocadodf["AveragePrice"].mean(axis = 0)
median_AveragePrice = avocadodf["AveragePrice"].median(axis = 0)

where_bigger = np.where((avocadodf["AveragePrice"] > mean_AveragePrice) & (avocadodf["AveragePrice"] > median_AveragePrice), 1, 0 )

where_bigger.sum()
```

So you got the data you need and now you need the test.  `np.where` will help you out

Comment: awesome... tried it and understood how it works as well.... thank u !

Comment: That is the best message that I could receive this Saturday morning.  Made my day! Thank you.